# Python - Difficulty joining multiple lines without depending on "\n"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using beautifulsoup to find all locations on a webpage, and it does.

```
get_location = second_soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class": "location"})
for local in get_location :
  if local:
    s = local.text
    s = s.replace("\n", "")
    s = s.replace("-", "") #removes the -
    s = s.split("|", 1)[0] #removes | and everything after it
    s = ''.join([i for i in s if not i.isdigit()]) #removes numbers from zip
    s = s.lstrip() #removes spaces
    s = s.rstrip() #removes spaces
    print(s)
```

I get the following result:

```
New York, NY
Brooklyn, NY
Johnville, KY
```

However, I need it like so:

`New York, NY, Brooklyn, NY, Johnville, KY`

Things I've tried:

1) instead of `s.replace("\n", "")` using `s.replace("\n", ", ")`

Results are identical, except when there was \n it replaced with `,` So I get:

```
, New York, NY, 
, Brooklyn, NY, 
, Johnville, KY,
```

2) Removing replace and using `s = '\n'.join([line.strip() for line in s])`

Results are weird, I get one character per line. Such as:

```
N
E
W


Y
O
R
K
```

## Edit

The reason I need it in a one-liner is that I'm inserting that into an array, and I'm unable to insert more than one line into an array, so I get `New York, NY` and that's it.

That's how I want my array:

`['New York, NY, Brooklyn, NY, Johnville, KY', 'Boston, MA, Miami, FL']` etc

Comment: `s = '\n'.join([line.strip() for line in s])` is surely doing the opposite of what you want?

Comment: @roganjosh that it is. I'm no python wizard.

Comment: You mention that you want to "insert into an array". You want a _numpy_ array output at the end or just a python list?

Comment: I presume the 'if' is actually intended inside the "for"?  **Please get the indentation correct when asking a python question**

Comment: @roganjosh I've edited my question to include the way I want my array.

Comment: @MartinBonner Done, thanks

Comment: Or did you mean list comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

I can't test since we don't have your data, but I think you want something like:

```
get_location = second_soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class": "location"})
rebuilt = []
for local in get_location :
    if local:
        s = local.text
        s = s.replace("\n", "")
        s = s.replace("-", "") #removes the -
        s = s.split("|", 1)[0] #removes | and everything after it
        s = ''.join([i for i in s if not i.isdigit()]) #removes numbers from zip
        s = s.strip() #removes spaces
        rebuilt.extend(s)
print(rebuilt)
```

Comment: Personally, I'd write `s = s.lstrip().rstrip()`.  I'd also probably write as `s = s.translate(None, "\n-0123456789)`, `s = s.split("|", 1)[0]`, `s = s.lstrip().rstrip()`

Comment: @MartinBonner I'm not actually sure `lstrip` and `rstrip` are relevant after the `i.isdigit()`, I was just setting up a test.

Comment: @MartinBonner it's not

Comment: D'oh!  `s = s.strip()` does it in one step!

Comment: Why would `isdigit()` strip spaces?

Comment: @MartinBonner oh boy, you're right, I've got it the wrong way round. I'll wait to see if there's feedback from the OP otherwise I'll delete

Comment: This almost works, except I get the array like so, `['N', 'e', 'w', ' ', 'Y', 'o', 'r', 'k']`

Comment: @Rosenberg try `rebuilt.extend([s])` instead. Does that work?

Comment: @roganjosh, it does, but the thing is, I get the results such as `['New York, NY', 'Brooklyn, NY', 'Johnville, KY']`, when I wanted it as `['New York, NY, Brooklyn, NY, Johnville, KY']`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to replace newlines with commas:

```
s = ', '.join(s.split('\n'))
```

However, it would be helpful if you could provide an example data blob that you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of your 'if' loop - print(s), as each line is printed with print's 'end' parameter as set to default = '\n'. Therefore, its printed in next line for each loop.
So if you set the parameter to comma(,) or as per your choice then output will be printed in same line.
Try this:--

```
print(s, end=',')
```